# Draw text line with padding using Apache PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox, java-7

I have an existing pdf where I need to draw a fixed length text without calculating the position for each character. By introducing four spaces between each character I nearly get the desired result but it is still not perfect.

**Q1**: I am wondering how would you manage a scenario like this, if there are more intelligent ways to achieve the same result.

Here is my sample code and a screenshot of the result PDF file:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class PdfWriteSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try (InputStream is = PdfWriteSample.class.getResourceAsStream("/template/Mod_F24_Ordinario.pdf")) {
            PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(is);
            PDPage firstPage = doc.getPage(0);
            PDFont pdfFont= PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
            int fontSize = 8;

            try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, firstPage, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND,true,true)) {
                contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize);
                contentStream.beginText();
                contentStream.newLineAtOffset(120,724);
                String text = "ABCSKL72E12N408X".replaceAll(".(?!$)", "$0    ");
                contentStream.showText(text);
                contentStream.endText();
            }
            doc.save(new File("results/newF24.pdf"));
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Q2**: To continue drawing text in the next fields, should I go on like this or is there e better way?

```
contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize);

contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(117, 724);
contentStream.setCharacterSpacing(9.2f);
contentStream.showText("ABCSKL72E12N408X");
contentStream.endText();

contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(117, 700);
contentStream.setCharacterSpacing(0f);
contentStream.showText("NAME");
contentStream.endText();
```

Comment: `setCharacterSpacing` or `showTextWithPositioning` might be what you need. Unless this is an acroform (i.e. PDF form fields), then there are better ways.

Comment: You use Helvetica. The letters in that font don't all have the same width. Thus, a constant gap in-between won't help, neither in the form of multiple space characters nor in that of a constant gap length.

Comment: `setCharacterSpacing` seems a good compromise.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr if `doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm()` is `null` it means this is not an acroform and the only way to fill the document is by drawing using `showText()`, right?

Comment: Yes indeed. (I found the document online at https://www.agenziaentrate.gov.it/portale/web/guest/schede/pagamenti/f24/modello-e-istruzioni-f24 )